# Assignment in SQL if value is null or not to two new vlaues

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to assing a value in a query depending on the state of the variable. For example like using the `COALESCE` command, but i need it to read as follows.

1. `if null assign a, else assign b.`

EX: `COALESCE(valToCheck, a, b)`

Is there a funciton like this? I cannot find anything online about it. It is currently being used in this line:

```
select distinct a.right_id, COALESCE(b.right_id, '0', '1') this_bit
from app_right a, (
                   select rol.app_role_id
                       ,rol.app_parent_id
                       ,rol.right_id 
                   from app_role rol 
                  where rol.application_id = @APP_ID
                 ) b
            CONNECT BY ( select b.app_role_id from app_user a
                 ,app_user_right_xref b 
             where a.user_id = b.user_id 
             and a.sec_user = p_sec_user)
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN valToCheck IS NULL THEN 'a' ELSE 'b' END`

Comment: coalesce returns first non-null in list, otherwise null

Comment: I need to do it while assigning the value in a query though. How would I do that?

Comment: you want to return data and assign ?

Comment: i can understand this_bit, (well not really cuz you should not use coalesce) but what exactly are you trying to do with `b.right_id`? are you trying to do a db update in the midst of a plain-jane select stmt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement:

```
select distinct 
    a.right_id,
    CASE WHEN b.right_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS this_bit
```

Note that if you are *truly* wanting a bit you should use `CAST`:

```
select distinct 
    a.right_id,
    CAST(CASE WHEN b.right_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS this_bit
```

Comment: Just wording, not needing cast.  Thanks everyone!